# Deploy on heroku with dpl not working with new farady version

Tags: heroku, gitlab-ci, faraday

My CI/CD on gitlab deploy code on heroku using dpl. It have been working like a charm until a new version of faraday (I guess it is the reason) is fetch.

Here is what I had in my gitlab CI terminal when it worked (yesterday) :

```
...
$ dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_STAGING_APP --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
Installing deploy dependencies
Successfully installed rendezvous-0.1.3
Successfully installed netrc-0.11.0
Successfully installed multipart-post-2.1.1
Successfully installed faraday-rack-1.0.0
Successfully installed faraday-patron-1.0.0
Successfully installed faraday-net_http_persistent-1.2.0
Successfully installed faraday-net_http-1.0.1
Successfully installed faraday-httpclient-1.0.1
Successfully installed faraday-excon-1.1.0
Successfully installed faraday-em_synchrony-1.0.0
Successfully installed faraday-em_http-1.0.0
Successfully installed faraday-1.8.0
Successfully installed dpl-heroku-1.10.16
13 gems installed
authentication succeeded
checking for app XXX
found app XXX
Preparing deploy
...
```

Here is what I get today :

```
...
$ dpl --provider=heroku --app=$HEROKU_STAGING_APP --api-key=$HEROKU_API_KEY
Installing deploy dependencies
Successfully installed rendezvous-0.1.3
Successfully installed netrc-0.11.0
Successfully installed faraday-2.0.0
Successfully installed dpl-heroku-1.10.16
4 gems installed
Preparing deploy
No stash entries found.
/usr/local/bundle/gems/faraday-2.0.0/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:230:in `ensure_adapter!': An attempt to run a request with a Faraday::Connection without adapter has been made. (RuntimeError)
Please set Faraday.default_adapter or provide one when initializing the connection.
...
```

I tried to add --skip_cleanup to dpl call [as seen here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/33115) but it is not working. Maybe I can force reussing the older version of faraday ? But I can't find any source to try this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be useful for this case

https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/issues/1247

Comment: Thanks you, it solved my problem before having a better and official fix. Solution exposed by @felin-arch in link does the job.