# Gitlab deploy to heroku failure

Tags: heroku, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-delivery, heroku-api

Gitlab fails to deploy to heroku when I push. [image]

When I first encountered the issue I referred to this [link](https://medium.com/swlh/how-do-i-deploy-my-code-to-heroku-using-gitlab-ci-cd-6a232b6be2e4) for configuration guidance. however when I push gitlab throws a RuntimeError that "ensure adapter! ": An attempt
to run a request with a Faraday:: Connection without adapter has been made.
In the process of trying to fix the issue I landed on this [repo](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/blob/50e3ebb80506343af4f08db1075c846732b8f8f7/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb#L229). Can anyone enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved with this:
https://github.com/travis-ci/dpl/issues/1247

Mentioned in this topic:
[Deploy on heroku with dpl not working with new farady version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70578474/deploy-on-heroku-with-dpl-not-working-with-new-farady-version)